# Yii vs pure php?

Tags: php, yii

Есть необходимость написать примерно след. функционал:

- мастера могут редактировать записи своего участка (состоит из нескольких участков);
- юниты участка могут проматривать данные своего подразделения;
- руководство может смотреть все участки (все).

Друг советует использовать yii, только я в нем ни в зуб ногой. Пхп ближе и роднее. Я, конечно, понимаю, что фреймворк круче и перспективнее, но вот какая у него гибкость? Предположим, на пхп я могу реализовать следующее: при нажатии на кнопку добавить запись - появляется строка, где он может задать все данные, но при добавлении я указываю номер оборудования onlyread, и пользователь технически не может его апдейтнуть. Так же по дефолту в иии создателю записи предоставляется и удаление. Мне это не нужно. Может, есть какие простые пути?

Comment: В Yii можно гибко настроить права для различных групп пользователей (RBAC), задавайте создателю записю права Owner и запретите Owner'ам удаление записи

Comment: я даже скажу такую штуку, что первый yii не бог весть как далеко от простого PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы неверно представляете себе, что такое framework, в частности yii.

Yii написан на php и служит для упрощения и ускорения разработки, так как в нем реализованы многие вещи, которые вам могу понадобяться.

То задание, которое вы описали, можно реализовать как на чистом php, так на yii. Чисто теоретически быстрее и проще выполнить его на yii. Но на практике вам придется сначала разобраться в yii, для чего вам понадобятся знания php, ОПП, sql.

P.S. Если это не задание-минутка для товарища, "чтоб отстал" и проект будет в дальнейшем развиваться или вы в дальнейшем пойдете по стезе разработчика, мой совет - грызите yii.